# python pandas csv exporting

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export

I've problem exporting a dataframe to CSV file.

Data types are String and Float64 values like this:

```
In [19]: segmenti_t0
Out[19]:
SEGM1  SEGM2
AD     P.S.         8.3
       SCREMATO     0.6
CRE    STD          1.2
FUN    INTERO       0.0
       P.S.         2.0
       SCREMATO     0.0
NORM   INTERO      13.1
       P.S.        69.5
       SCREMATO     5.2
Name: Quota volume_t0
```

I try to export this dataframe with this command:

```
IN [20]: segmenti_t0.to_csv('C:Users\MarioRossi\prova.csv', sep=";")
```

When I try to open it with Excel or I try to import it in excel from the csv file with formatting parameters I obtain really strange formatting for float values like 69.5000 or 5.2.0000000 or date times formatting too like this:

```
NORM    INTERO  13.01
NORM    P.S.    69.05.00
NORM    SCREMATO    5.02
```

Consider that I m using European format ("," as decimal as I use to import the original raw data from csv files).

Please help me: I developed a software (with GUI and so on) and I cant deliver it for that reason!

Thanks

Comment: What does the csv look like when opened with a text editor (e.g. in notepad)

Comment: like this:

AD;P.S.;8.3
AD;SCREMATO;0.6
CRE;STD;1.2
FUN;INTERO;0.0
FUN;P.S.;2.0
FUN;SCREMATO;0.0
NORM;INTERO;13.1
NORM;P.S.;69.5
NORM;SCREMATO;5.2

Comment: if I save it from notepad and I try to open it with excel I obtain the same problem:
AD P.S. 8.03
AD SCREMATO 0.06
CRE STD 1.02
FUN INTERO 0.00
FUN P.S. 2.00
FUN SCREMATO 0.00
NORM INTERO 13.01
NORM P.S. 69.05.00
NORM SCREMATO 5.02

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) DataFrame method:

```
# first convert Series to DataFrame
df_segmenti_t0 = DataFrame(segmenti_t0)

# save as excel spreadsheet
df_segmenti_t0.to_excel('prova.xls')
```

Comment: I obtain this:                                                    In [3]: segmenti_t0.to_excel('prova.csv')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Windows\system32\<ipython-input-3-2adcb4ade28e> in <module>()
----> 1 segmenti_t0.to_excel('prova.csv')

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: @ManuelZompetta I missed it was a series not a DataFrame, please see updated answer. `to_excel` is a DataFrame method, so you must convert the Series to a DataFrame (`segmenti_t0 = pd.DataFrame(segmenti_t0)`).

Comment: Now I obtain this:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, path)
   2108             self.fm_date = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='YYYY-MM-DD')
   2109         else:
-> 2110             from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
   2111             self.book = Workbook()#optimized_write=True)
   2112

Comment: and...

ImportError: No module named openpyxl.workbook

maybe the library is not properly installed? I work on Enthought distribution 7.3

Thanks again!

Comment: @ManuelZompetta it looks like `openpyxl` is not in [Enthought Free](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php), you'll need to install it separately...

Comment: Ok. I'll try asap. Thanks again.
Do you know how to install to a specific Python distribution? I've many installed on my pc and I do not use a lot of imported libraries...
M

Comment: Great thanks, I have installed with: python install setup.py and, thanks God, library has been installed in the correct folder of the Enthought distribution:
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
I have anyway many Python installation on my system (Mac OSX 10.8) and I would like to know how is possible to install to a specific Python installation (ex. Python 3.3): I ve read documentation about install command but I had not understood well or python install setup.py +path of packages site do not function. Thanks Hayden

Comment: Now if I import openpyxl from the pylab shell the situation is ok but if I write your instructions for the conversion to data frame and then: segmenti_t0.to_excel('/Users/manuelzompetta/Desktop/prova.xls')
I obtain this error:

ImportError: No module named xlwt

Sob.... M

Comment: @ManuelZompetta you need to install that too (it shouldn't go much deeper, and once you've installed all these you won't need to again!) :)

Comment: Great, now the file is created but with number in text format with "." instead of "," for decimals. I think I have to find in the openpyxl documentation the correct parameters to set the decimals...
M

Comment: Finally the situation is ok. I have just to understand how to export many dataframes on the same excel workbook... Not easy but I feel close to the arrival... HAve you any idea about that? Is better I write another post? Dear Hayden, I m not a professional programmer but just a marketers: programming its nice but hard...)))

Comment: Upvote and accept if this answers been helpful, and ask this as another question :) These comments are getting quite long!

Comment: I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet) myself, as I am not sure. Hopefully someone will know :)

Comment: Finally I arrive to the solution in the night. Tks. More more difficult is to write many small dataframes on the same sheet... I have to write an answer for that...)))