# Save list of DataFrames to multisheet Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

How can I export a list of DataFrames into one Excel spreadsheet?
The docs for [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) state:

> Notes
>   If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be added
>   to the existing workbook.  This can be used to save different
>   DataFrames to one workbook
>
> `writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')`
>   `df1.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')`
>   `df2.to_excel(writer, 'sheet2')`
>   `writer.save()`

Following this, I thought I could write a function which saves a list of DataFrames to one spreadsheet as follows:

```
from openpyxl.writer.excel import ExcelWriter
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
    writer.save()
```

However (with a list of two small DataFrames, each of which can save `to_excel` individually), an exception is raised *(Edit: traceback removed)*:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'worksheets'
```

Presumably I am not calling [`ExcelWriter`](http://www.nullege.com/codes/search?cq=openpyxl.writer.excel.ExcelWriter) correctly, how should I be in order to do this?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You should be using pandas own `ExcelWriter` class:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
# from pandas.io.parsers import ExcelWriter
```

Then the `save_xls` function works as expected:

```
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
            df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
```

Comment: why not just `df.to_excel('file_path')`?

Comment: How are you finding the speed of this? I tried to do the same thing yesterday and found that writing a dataframe with 2000 columns to an .xlsx file was taking about 16s per 100 rows on a decent workstation with solid state drive. Some quick profiling with %prun in ipython showed this to be due to the XML processing. In the end I got the data inte Excel by going via CSV because the ExcelWriter speed was prohibitively slow.

Comment: Still as slow in 2018.

Comment: You can also use `ExcelWriter` as a context manager. `with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer: df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name)`

Comment: Thanks Andy. Would you mind explaining the `'sheet%s' % n` bit please? What does it do and how does it work?

Comment: @BowenLiu That's just naming the sheets to sheet1, sheet2, etc.

Comment: This seems to overwrite an existing file. How does one write and keep existing file? Thank you

Comment: I had to leave out writer.save() for this to work for me.

Comment: `writer.save()` is already called when the context manager exits, don't manually call it again.

Comment: Is there a way you could amend your code so that the sheet tabs are named according to the dataframe please?

Answer (score 39):

In case anyone needs an example using a dictionary of dataframes:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def save_xls(dict_df, path):
    """
    Save a dictionary of dataframes to an excel file, 
    with each dataframe as a separate page
    """

    writer = ExcelWriter(path)
    for key in dict_df.keys():
        dict_df[key].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)

    writer.save()
```

example:
`save_xls(dict_df = my_dict, path = '~/my_path.xls')`

Comment: This really saved my day. But there is one thing I don't understand although it worked. What does the part `'%s' % key` do? Would you mind explaining it? Thanks!

Comment: @BowenLiu that takes the dictionary key value, and uses it for the page name in the excel sheet. '%s' is a placeholder that is filled in with "key". Hope that helps.

Comment: It worked great for me, just one little addition: add `writer.close()` at the end. I have python 3.7 and windows 10 setup, Microsoft Excel would not save the changes made to file because python would be accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there can be issues(Writing an excel file containing unicode), if there are some non supporting character type in the data frame. To overcome it we can use '**xlsxwriter**' package as in below case:

for below code:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlsxwriter
writer = ExcelWriter('notes.xlsx')
for key in dict_df:
        data[key].to_excel(writer, key,index=False)
writer.save()
```

I got the error as "IllegalCharacterError"

The code that worked:

```
%pip install xlsxwriter
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlsxwriter
writer = ExcelWriter('notes.xlsx')
for key in dict_df:
        data[key].to_excel(writer, key,index=False,engine='xlsxwriter')
writer.save()
```