# Export many small DataFrames to a single Excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, export, pandas

With [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet/14225838#14225838), it is possible to export every data frame in a new worksheet iterating data frames list:

```
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer,'sheet_dati%s' % n)
    writer.save()
save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path)
```

But its possible to export two or more data frames in a single worksheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have multiple `DataFrames` on the same sheet *how* would you combine them? Instead [**merge, join, or concatenate**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html) them into a single `DataFrame` beforehand as pandas gives you multiple ways of doing so. And then do your export.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this: ?

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
def dfs2xlsx(list_dfs,xls_path = None):
    #save_xls([df1,df2],'output1.xlsx')
    if xls_path == None :
        xls_path = '~tmp.xlsx'
    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    i=0
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',startcol=i,startrow =2)
        i+= len(df.columns) + 2
    writer.save()
    os.system('start excel.exe %s' %(writer.path ))
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going to be better doing a [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) of these DataFrames **before** exporting (via [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)). That is:

```
pd.concat(list_dfs).to_excel(xls_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the integration of data frames is messy (they are merged together and not in sequence) when exported on the sheet. Unfortunately I think I should have to study a lot merge, join, concatenate functions in order to have usable and correctly formatted data on the sheet. Anyway this command is useful too. Thanks. M

Comment: @ManuelZompetta merging in pandas itself isn't too tricky, best of luck :)

Comment: +1 for Manuel, before the pandas.ExcelWriter has a write-rows method, which could be used for this purpose. But I noticed that recent version removes this method. I would argue sometimes people have some dataframs that have good reason to be separated.

Comment: more comments: I just notice now you have startrow and startcol in the pa.DataFrame.to_excel method, so one probale workaround is to calculate the length that needed.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for ashkan's answer. This method allows you to write the headers multiple times, and do things like leaving space between the individual dataframes much more easily than inserting blank rows into one larger concat'd dataframe. For instance:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(filepath, filename))
for item in list_of_dataframes:
    item.to_excel(writer, "sheetname", startcol=0, startrow=n)
    n += len(item.index) + 2
writer.save()
```

This allows you to write multiple (possibly different or unrelated) dataframes into one excel sheet, one after another, leaving a blank line between each as you go down the page.

Comment: This post is _awfully_ close to being commentary on another answer, rather than it's own stand-alone post. If you've got additional information to add to an answer, that's fine. But just commenting on a post is what comments are for.

Comment: As a new member I was unable to comment, I tried that first. Noted for next time :)