# How to write summary of spark sql dataframe to excel file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very large Dataframe with 8000 columns and 50000 rows.
I want to write its statistics information into excel file.
I think we can use `describe()` method. But how to write it to excel in good format. Thanks

Comment: Excel can open a csv (comma-separated values) file as an ordinary spreadsheet. So the easiest thing is to just print any output as comma-separated values and then you can just open it with Excel.

Comment: True, but best to convert it to a pandas dataframe first so you don't have to worry about part files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type for `describe` is a pyspark dataframe. The easiest way to get the `describe` dataframe into an excel readable format is to convert it to a pandas dataframe and then write the pandas dataframe out as a csv file as below

```
import pandas
df.describe().toPandas().to_csv('fileOutput.csv')
```

If you want it in excel format, you can try below

```
import pandas
df.describe().toPandas().to_excel('fileOutput.xls', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index = False)
```

Note, the above requires xlwt package to be installed (pip install xlwt in the command line)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had tried this. But the output in CSV file does not look much user friendly or readable.
SO I wanted it in excel format. Thanks

Comment: Excel can open csvs

Comment: @Ajg updated with info on writing a pandas dataframe to excel

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate

Comment: Can we use the above to write dataframes to multiple tabs in an excel sheet?

Comment: you'd have to refactor the code a bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet