# Excel export using While loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, while-loop, export-to-excel

I am new to Python. I am working on a large analytic program, and this is a snippet of it. Right now, this snippet exports multiple excel files. Is it possible to save what is done per loop on a sheet within a single excel document? So basically right now, it exports 5 files, rather than exporting 5 separate files, can I use this loop and export 1 file, that has 5 sheets?

```
x = 0
y = 0
#these are empty variables for the while loop


#while loop that loops up to the system amount
#breaks up df into systems
#exports excel for each system
while x < int(SystemCount): 
    x += 1
    y += 1 
    System = minus4[minus4['System'] == "System " + str(y)]
    System.to_excel('U4Sys' +  str(y) + '.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
    print(System.head())
```

the print at the end prints this

```
    email    System
test1@test.com  System 1
test2@test.com  System 1
test3@test.com  System 1
test4@test.com  System 1
test5@test.com  System 1

         email    System
test1@test.com  System 2
test2@test.com  System 2
test3@test.com  System 2
test4@test.com  System 2
test5@test.com  System 2

         email    System
test1@test.com  System 3
test2@test.com  System 3
test3@test.com  System 3
test4@test.com  System 3
test5@test.com  System 3
```

Thank you for taking your time to read this!

Comment: What library are you using to send that to Excel?

Comment: Have you tried XlsxWriter?
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Hey Sorry, I am using Pandas, ExcelWriter, and ExcelFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (to account for OP using `pandas` and `ExcelWriter`):

You need to define your target file with `ExcelWriter` and then write to it with variable sheet names. Also offering some Python clean-up for your iteration:

```
#breaks up df into systems
#exports excel for each system

writer = ExcelWriter('U4SysOutput.xlsx')
for x in range(1, int(SystemCount)+1): 

    System = minus4[minus4['System'] == "System " + str(x)]
    System.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet{}'.format(x), index=False)
    print(System.head())
```

Comment: I am using Pandas, ExcelWriter and Excel File. I tried the code above and it just saves the last iteration of the loop. So only System 5 is saved into the excel and not 1, 2, 3 or 4

Comment: Ah. In that case, you have a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `pandas.ExcelWriter()` in `pandas.to_excel()`

Here is a simplified version of your process:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Output Excel file:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("your_excel_filepath.xlsx")

# Your variables:
x, y = 0, 0

# The loop:             
while x < 5:

    x += 1
    y += 1 

    # The DataFrame for this iteration:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns=list("ABCD"))

    # Write the DataFrame to a new sheet:
    df.to_excel(writer, "sheet_{}".format(x))
writer.save()
```