# Export to csv in perfect format

Tags: html, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to print this data in csv so that i can loop many companies for my  web scraping code.

I am getting this code with the help of  stackoverflow itself and want to get this printed format to excel or csv with or without Rs 149 each column .

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
headers = [header.text for header in soup.select('h3.pull-left')]
tables = pd.read_html(url)
items = zip(headers,tables)
for header, table in items:
    print(header)
    print(table)
```

**

```
Certificates
         Date                         Title   ₨ 149 Each
0  2006-04-24  Certificate of Incorporation  Add to Cart
1  2006-04-24  Certificate of Incorporation  Add to Cart
Other Documents Attachment
         Date Title   ₨ 149 Each
0  2006-04-24   AOA  Add to Cart
1  2006-04-24   AOA  Add to Cart
2  2006-04-24   MOA  Add to Cart
3  2006-04-24   MOA  Add to Cart
Annual Returns and balance sheet Eform
         Date                    Title   ₨ 149 Each
0  2006-04-24  Annual Return 2002_2003  Add to Cart
1  2006-04-24  Annual Return 2003_2004  Add to Cart
```

**

Comment: Python comes with its own [CSV input and output library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Please try that first as currently the question is a bit too broad, IMO.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225838/1240268

Comment: I still cant figure out a way to print it to csv

Comment: You’re storing the table using pandas. Why not use 'df.to_csv()' ?

Comment: That is not happening as header value is str and table is df.

Comment: You can use that string to set the column names of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear exactly what you want as your expected output. But you can use pandas to write it to csv once you combine the dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
headers = [header.text for header in soup.select('h3.pull-left')]
tables = pd.read_html(url)

tables = [ table[1:] for idx, table in enumerate(tables) ]

df = pd.concat(tables)   
df.columns = headers 
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)


df.to_csv('path/to/filename.csv', index=False)
```