# Write data in multiple sheets in excel using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I wanted to make multiple sheets in excel using python pandas.df has the data which i wanted to write in excel using excel writer in python pandas. The column 'Data frame' has different values and wanted to make sheets based on the comparing the values.  I wrote the code as given below :

'''

```
'with pd.ExcelWriter('output3.xlsx') as writer:'
        df[df["Data frame"]==0].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='zero')
        df[df["Data frame"]==1].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='one')
```

'''

but I  am getting error message as follows:

'''

```
 File "<ipython-input-11-e151f874b16f>", line 3
    df[df["Data frame"]==1].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='one')
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

'''

can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: try df.loc[df['Data frame']==0]...

Comment: Still same error is coming.

Comment: If i have only one line then it is working. For more than one lines only this problem is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your original code to write to excel? As for me it works, but in this question it looks like you have a indent that is not needed.

Or you can make two different dataframes first:

```
     df1 = df[df['Data frame']==0]
     df2 = df[df['Data frame']==1]
```

and than write this to two sheets with writer:

```
     # Create a new excel workbook
     writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output3.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

     df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='zero')
     df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='one')
```

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter('output3.xlsx') as writer:
     df[df["Data frame"]==0].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='zero')
     df[df["Data frame"]==1].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='one')

Comment: Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet 
Perhaps this helps you?

Comment: the link to put different dataframes in one sheet. What i want is to put in different sheets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas
And this one?