# How to replace one sheet in Excel and keep all the other existing sheets?

Tags: python, pandas

There are two sheets in the excel file: SheetA and SheetB

My SheetA has formula linking data to SheetB. I want to update SheetB on daily basis so that SheetA's info could be updated on daily basis as well.

My code is as follows but it deletes SheetA.

```
path1 = <file location>
book = load_workbook(path1)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path1, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df.to_excel(writer, "SheetB", index = False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save list of DataFrames to multisheet Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: Thanks! I just tried, but my SheetA is still deleted. Is there a way to keep SheetA while replacing SheeB?

Comment: Did you read both sheets? Once you read in both sheets, you can make your changes to the second one and write them both using the technique from the link

Comment: you mean read SheetA and then write SheetA again? wouldn't that break the formulas besides I also have some charts on that sheet.