# Xlsxwriter writer is writing its own sheets and deletes existing ones

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am wring dataframes to excel. Maybe I am not doing it correctly,

When I use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

start = datetime.now()


df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\harsh\Google Drive\Oddsportal\Files\Oddsportal "
                   r"Data\Historical Worksheet\data.xlsx", sheet_name='x1')
df['run_time'] = start

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\harsh\Google Drive\Oddsportal\Files\Oddsportal "
                  r"Data\Pre-processed\oddsportal_upcoming_matches.csv")
df1['run_time'] = start
concat = [df, df1]
df_c = pd.concat(concat)

path = r"C:\Users\harsh\Google Drive\Oddsportal\Files\Oddsportal Data\Historical Worksheet\data.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x1')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x2')
df_c.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='upcoming_archive')
writer.save()
writer.close()

print(df_c.head())
```

The dataframes are written in their respective sheets and all the other existing sheets get deleted.

How can i write to only the respective sheets and not disturb the other existing ones?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet) help?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the append mode and set `if_sheet_exists` to `replace` and use `openpyxl` as engine.

Replace:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
```

By:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl',
                         if_sheet_exists='replace')  # <- HERE
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

> **mode{‘w’, ‘a’}, default ‘w’**

Comment: I got this error: `raise ValueError("Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!")
ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!`

Comment: When I try `mode = w` I get this error: `File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.book = Workbook(self.handles.handle, **engine_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname'`

Comment: Use openpyxl as engine (I updated my answer).

Comment: [th is my code](https://pastebin.com/TaxxFnz1) and I amgetting this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \scratch_4.py", line 37, in <module>
    writer = df_c.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\harsh\Google Drive\Oddsportal\Files\Oddsportal Data\Historical Worksheet\data.xlsx", sheetname = 'upcoming_archive',
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5478, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ExcelWriter'` and nothing is written

Comment: I am getting this error: `ValueError: Sheet 'upcoming_archive' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.`

Comment: @PyNoob_N. I updated my answer. Now it should be right.

Answer (score 1):

`xlsxwriter` is Not meant to alter an existing `xlsx` file. The only savier is `openpyxl`, which does the job but is hard to learn. I even wrote a simple python script to fill the gap to write a bunch of rows or columns in a sheet - [openpyxl_writers.py](https://github.com/Zhaoxun/openpyxl-1)

Answer (score 0):

While writing new (or overwriting the existing sheets), you need to read and write the previously existing sheets as well which you want to be persisted.

```py
workbook = load_workbook(path)    # Load the workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
writer.book = workbook            # Assign workbook to writer's book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)  #Read existing sheets

# Now write the new sheets (or overwrite the existing sheets)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x1')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x2')
df_c.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='upcoming_archive')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

You can always exclude the sheets you are about to overwrite while assigning the existing sheets to the `writer.sheets`.

Comment: I am getting this error:  `File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

Comment: Is the file a zip compressed file?

Comment: No, its an xlsx file

Comment: Okay, let me test and update the code.

Comment: That is fixed, you just need to load the workbook first before opening it with the pd.ExcelWriter