# Iteratively read excel sheet names, split and save them as new columns for each sheet in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have many excel files with the multiple sheets as the following file `data1.xlsx`:

Sheet 1: 2021_q1_bj

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  23  2
1  2  3  45  5
```

Sheet 2: 2021_q2_bj

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  23  6
1  2  3  45  7
```

Sheet 3: 2019_q1_sh

```
   a  b   c
0  1  2  23
1  2  3  45
```

Sheet 4: 2019_q2_sh

```
   a  b   c
0  1  2  23
1  2  3  40
```

I need to obtain sheet name for each sheet, then split them by `_`, store the first part as `year`, the second part as `quarter`, and the last part as `city`.

Finaly I will save them back to excel file with multiple sheets.

ie., for the first sheet:

```
   a  b   c  d  year quarter city
0  1  2  23  2  2021      q1   bj
1  2  3  45  5  2021      q1   bj
2  1  2  23  6  2021      q1   bj
3  2  3  45  7  2021      q1   bj
```

How could I achive this in Python? Thanks.

To loop all the excel files:

```
base_dir = './'
file_list = os.listdir(base_dir)

for file in file_list:
    if '.xlsx' in file:
        file_path = os.path.join(file_path, )
        dfs = pd.read_excel()
```

Comment: with `sheet_name=None`, `pandas.read_excel` reads all sheets from a file into a dict of dataframes, where the sheetnames are the dict keys. Given that, it should be easy enough to loop through all the files and do this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `f = pd.ExcelFile('data1.xlsx')` to read the excel file in as an object, then loop through the list of sheet names by iterating through `f.sheet_names`, splitting each sheet name such as the "2019_q1_sh" string into the appropriate `year, quarter, city` and setting these as values of new columns in the DataFrame you are reading in from each sheet.

Then create a dictionary with sheet names as keys, and the corresponding modified DataFrame as the values. You can create a custom `save_xls` function that takes in such a dictionary and saves it, as described in [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet).

Update: since you want to loop through all excel files in your current directory, you can use the `glob` library to get all of the files with extension `.xlsx` and loop through each of these files, read them in, and save a new file with the string `new_` in front of the file name

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob

"""
Save a dictionary of dataframes to an excel file, with each dataframe as a separate page

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225676/save-list-of-dataframes-to-multisheet-excel-spreadsheet
"""
def save_xls(dict_df, path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(path)
    for key in dict_df:
        dict_df[key].to_excel(writer, key)
    writer.save()

## loop through all excel files
for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    f = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    dict_dfs = {}
    for sheet_name in f.sheet_names:
        df_new = f.parse(sheet_name = sheet_name)

        ## get the year and quarter from the sheet name 
        year, quarter, city = sheet_name.split("_")
        df_new["year"] = year
        df_new["quarter"] = quarter
        df_new["city"] = city

        ## populate dictionary 
        dict_dfs[sheet_name] = df_new 

    save_xls(dict_df = dict_dfs, path = "new_" + filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I would like to loop all the excel file and apply method above as you posted to each one?

Comment: Yes you can do that - create an outer loop before you define the pd.ExcelFile object `f` and end the loop after you run `save_xls`. you'll also want to make sure that you don't hardcode the filenames like I did

Comment: @ahbon sure you can use a package like `glob` to read in all files with extension `.xlsx`

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help, I'll test with my real data, have a good day.

Comment: No problem! Glad my answer was helpful